# How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I want to get one element that is already on the page in the DOM and append it to another `<div>` or element in the DOM.

I don’t want to append a string but I used this:

```js
$("#dialog-form-Member").append($("div#MemberFormWrapper"));
```

Which took my element and put it where I wanted it, *but* it also got rid of the first element in order to put it in the other other element.

Example:

```html
<div id="one">
  I want to put this div into div two without div one disappearing. Keep both divs visible at the same time.
</div>

<div id="two">
  I want the content of div one to show here and keep both divs visible.
</div>
```

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: So you want to copy/clone the first div?

Comment: Closely related: [Why do multiple `.appendTo` calls on a newly created jQuery element only append it once?](/q/5529091/4642212). See also [How to 'copy and paste' an element in jQuery?](/a/8015446/4642212) and [why is my jquery Append not working properly?](/a/8421468/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe what youre looking for is [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I found what I was looking for. Clone was the answer, but we are using asp.net and that just clones our form, which I was not thinking that about so the form can actually only be on the page once. 
Instead I am using a modal and just appending and removing the form from the first div and appending it to the second div(modal) and when a user cancels the modal I just reappend it to the first div.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

You need to clone the element before appending in order to retain the original one.

```
 $("#dialog-form-Member").append($("div#MemberFormWrapper").clone());
```

In order to retain event handlers and/or data  check the parameter versions of the clone method @ http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Excerpt from http://api.jquery.com/clone/:

> Description: Create a deep copy of the
>   set of matched elements.
>
> version added: 1.0.clone( [
>   withDataAndEvents ] )
>   withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers should be
>   copied along with the elements. As of
>   jQuery 1.4, element data will be
>   copied as well.
>
> version added: 1.5.clone( [
>   withDataAndEvents ], [
>   deepWithDataAndEvents ] )
>   withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers and data should
>   be copied along with the elements. The
>   default value is false. *For 1.5.0 the
>   default value is incorrectly true.
>   This will be changed back to false in
>   1.5.1 and up.
>
> deepWithDataAndEventsA Boolean
>   indicating whether event handlers and
>   data for all children of the cloned
>   element should be copied. By default
>   its value matches the first argument's
>   value (which defaults to false).

Comment: This answer could use a more in-depth explanation. It’s worth mentioning that a node (every element is a node and jQuery objects work the same way) can only be attached to the DOM _once_, at most. Any attempt to insert an already attached node will just _move_ the node elsewhere, i.e. detach the node and attach it at the new location. This is also documented in [jQuery’s documentation on `.append`](//api.jquery.com/append) (and others): _“If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)”_.

Answer (score 4):

You are appending the entire element, you just need the HTML.

```
$("#two").append($("#one").html());
```

Outputs:

```
<div id="one">
     I want to put this div into div 2 without div one disappearing. Keep both divs visible at the same time.
</div>

<div id="two">
     I want div one content to show here and keep both divs visible.  I want to put this div into div 2 without div one disappearing. Keep both divs visible at the same time.
</div>
```

Or, as the other answers suggest, you can use `clone()`, but be careful as that will make 2 elements with the ID `one` and that's a problem.

```
$("#two").append($("#one").clone());
```

Outputs:

```
<div id="one">
     I want to put this div into div 2 without div one disappearing. Keep both divs visible at the same time.
</div>

<div id="two">
     I want div one content to show here and keep both divs visible.
     <div id="one">
         I want to put this div into div 2 without div one disappearing. Keep both divs visible at the same time.
     </div>
</div>
```

Notice how there are 2 `one` elements, you will need to change the ID of one of them.

```
$('#one', '#two').attr('id', 'three');
```

Comment: that will copy over the contents of "div#MemberFormWrapper but not the div tags itself...

Comment: @FatherStorm: I know, the OP didn't specify that this wasn't what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element before appending.

```
$("#two").append($("div#one").clone());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWQFE/)

Answer (score 0):

make a full(deep) copy using .clone() a nd append it to the element you want to add it to...

```
$('div#MemberFormWrapper').clone().appendTo('#dialog-form-Membe');
```